# Is there a way to update laravel cashier's stripe secret config?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

In my laravel 7 application that uses laravel cashier version 12.4 I was trying to encrypt the stripe secret key and put inside .env and wanted to decrypt it before laravel cashier use that key. I did this to add addidtional layer of security to payment handling function to my application.

Here's what I did but seems like laravel cashier still getting the original config within services.

In .env file I put an encrypted stripe secret key like this:

```
STRIPE_SECRET=eyJpdiI6InRGTE9KVHNYemtJUnNXUFE4andDS2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWCtNU21yeVNuWFk4K1k1cFQweDZkWTZ6dytJRW1sRnVqd2doR1dJOHBPdFJ3YUJyNjNyMmErMGwrRHJYWk55VmdrOG9WQW8xV2w3ZzlaUUk5c1VMOWJqWlZKNU9reU5pMzh2L2NWQTk3WHRTc3RiRUlVS0JSQ2szdEdKOTkxelAwY3BaL01yQkhWWFZpWHl5SlU5VStaZ0pmV0tTN29tK0V2OUNRMkpLR3c4PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM3NGI0NzdmNWI0ZjBjNzFkYTMzMmNmMTAxMzVmOTc5YWRkN2I4NmU0MDlhOGJkYTMyOWEyODAxMjE5ZTdhZjQifQ==
```

And then in my controller that handles creating stripe customers like this:

```
$stripeSecret = config('services.stripe.secret');
$stripeSecret = decrypt($stripeSecret);
Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSecret);

$intent = $user->createSetupIntent();
        
dd($intent);
```

And when I tried to die dump, I keep on getting an error like this:

```
Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException
Invalid API Key provided: eyJpdiI6******************
```

I think laravel schier still get those original value from either .env because I also tried many workarounds I even tried overriding values from services:

```
'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET')
    ],
```

Somewhere in the application `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $stripeEncrypted = encrypt(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $stripeSecret = decrypt($stripeEncrypted);

        Cashier::stripeOptions([
            'secret_key' => $stripeSecret,
        ]);
   }
```

I also tried creating a `UpdateStripeConfigMiddleware` middleware to update the conifg service in stripe:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class UpdateStripeConfigMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Update the Stripe secret key in the .env file
        $decryptedKey = decrypt(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        // Update the Stripe secret key in the config
        Config::set('services.stripe.secret', $decryptedKey);

        return $next($request);
    }
}

Register the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php file
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\UpdateStripeConfigMiddleware::class,
];
```

What are ways do you guys to update stripe secret within config/services in a way that laravel cashier uses the decrypted stripe secret key? Any thougths on this highly appreciated.